# Create array in SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and I have this data structure:

```
A     B
-------
1     a
1     a
1     b
1     c
1     c
1     c
1     d
2     e
2     e
```

I need a query that produces this result:

```
1    4     {{c,3},{a,2},{b,1},{d,1}}
2    1     {{e,2}}
```

A=1, 4 rows total with A=1, the partial counts (3 rows with c value, 2 rows with a value, .....)

- The distinct values of column "A"
- The count of all rows related to the "A" value
- An array contains all the elements related to the "A" value and the relative count of itself

The sort needed for the array is based of the count of each group (like the example 3,2,1,1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT a
     , sum(ab_ct)::int AS ct_total
     , count(*)::int   AS ct_distinct_b
     , array_agg(b || ', ' || ab_ct::text) AS b_arr
FROM  (
    SELECT a, b, count(*) AS ab_ct
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY a, b
    ORDER  BY a, ab_ct DESC, b  -- append "b" to break ties in the count
    ) t
GROUP  BY a
ORDER  BY ct_total DESC;
```

Returns:

- `ct_total`: total count of `b` per `a`.
- `ct_distinct_b`: count of distinct `b` per `a`.
- `b_arr`: array of `b` plus frequency of `b`, sorted by frequency of `b`.

Ordered by total count of `b` per `a`.

Alternatively, you can use an [`ORDER BY` clause within the aggregate call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in PostgreSQL 9.0 or later. Like:

```
SELECT a
     , sum(ab_ct)::int AS ct_total
     , count(*)::int   AS ct_distinct_b
     , array_agg(b || ', ' || ab_ct::text ORDER BY a, ab_ct DESC, b) AS b_arr
FROM  (
    SELECT a, b, count(*) AS ab_ct
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY a, b
    ) t
GROUP  BY a
ORDER  BY ct_total DESC;
```

May be clearer. But it's typically slower. And sorting rows in a subquery works for simple queries like this one. More explanation:

- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213724/3684)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this should do it:

```
SELECT a, 
       count(*) as cnt,
       array_agg(b) as all_values
FROM your_table
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(*), array_agg(b)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY A
```