# Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm having a table like this

| Movie | Actor |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |

I want to get the name of a movie and all actors in that movie, and I want the result to be in a format like this:

| Movie | ActorList |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1, 2, 3 |

How can I do it?

Comment: then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365467/postgresql-9-1-how-to-concatenate-rows-in-array-without-duplicates-join-anothe

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Simpler with the aggregate function [**`string_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) (Postgres 9.0 or later):

```
SELECT movie, string_agg(actor, ', ') AS actor_list
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The `1` in `GROUP BY 1` is a positional reference and a shortcut for `GROUP BY movie` in this case.

`string_agg()` expects data type `text` as input. Other types need to be cast explicitly (`actor::text`) - *unless* an implicit cast to `text` is defined - which is the case for all other string types (`varchar`, `character`, `name`, ...) and some other types.

As [isapir commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#comment80744041_15850510), you can add an `ORDER BY` clause in the aggregate call to get a sorted list - should you need that. Like:

```
SELECT movie, string_agg(actor, ', ' ORDER BY actor) AS actor_list
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

But it's typically faster to sort rows in a subquery. See:

- [Create array in SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796092/postgres-sql-create-array-in-select/9796438#9796438)

Comment: I didn't know Postgres supported positional column references like that, and can't think of any good reason to use them, but otherwise this is spot on.

Comment: @IMSoP: It's just a syntactical convenience I slipped in. A good use case would be a complex expressions in the `SELECT` list or with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Small note - might need to `actor::TEXT` if `actor` is an `INT`. At least, I get an error trying to `string_agg` `INT`s in Postgres 9.5 - but otherwise, this was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @dwanderson: I added a note accordingly.

Comment: The above works but I get (...) on longer strings :(

Comment: @Chris: Probably an issue with your client settings, unrelated to the query. Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23568429/939860

Comment: Worth noting that an optional `ORDER BY` clause can go into the `string_agg` function after the delimiter argument, e.g. `string_agg(actor, ', ' ORDER BY actor DESC)`

Comment: late comment but a quick note on this nice, succinct solution. I found that this was actually consistently slower than the solution from @hims056 for my use case. (avg. 280ms vs 200ms). I'm a SQL/PostgreSQL novice and haven't been able to set up a SQLFiddle or similar, I'm afraid. Do you know of any obvious reason?

Comment: dear @ErwinBrandstetter, is there possibility to transform second value not as string but as a json?

Comment: @Pyrejkee: Certainly. Here are a couple of options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486910/939860

Comment: Another note that you can use an optional `DISTINCT` clause that can go into `string_agg` function before the first parameter. e.g. `string_agg(DISTINCT actor, ', ')`

Answer (score 91):

You can use `array_agg` function for that:

```
SELECT "Movie",
array_to_string(array_agg(distinct "Actor"),',') AS Actor
FROM Table1
GROUP BY "Movie";
```

Result:

| MOVIE | ACTOR |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,3 |
| B | 4 |

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/62f90/1)

For more See [9.18. Aggregate Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: what is the difference between string~agg and array-agg?

Comment: @mercury, string-agg makes field with string type, that is where all elements of string_agg's argument is concatenated into single string, array-agg makes field with type array of, e.g., strings, that is where all elements of array_agg's argument will be of its original type.