# How to find a field with some specific value in another field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns `MessageID` and `FlowStatusID`.

I want to find `MessageID`'s which have a `FlowStatusID` is one specific value with a special sequence.

For example I want to find `MessageID`'s where the `FlowStatusID` contains the sequence of these numbers: 105,81,21

```
MessageID   FlowStatusID
-------------------------
    1            11
    1           105
    2           105
    2            81
    2            21
    3            81
    4           105
    4            81
    4            21
    5            21
    5           105
```

The result must be 2, 4

Comment: why you want to get `2,4`

Comment: Because they contain the sequence 105,81,21 in FlowStatusID. @user3237339 Do they have to be in that order also? What defines the order of the records?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select MessageIDfrom t group by MessageID having count(*) =3 ;
```

Or

```
select MessageID from (
select t.MessageID from t where FlowStatusID=21 
union all 
select t.MessageID from t where FlowStatusID=81 
union  all
select t.MessageID from t where FlowStatusID=105 )
as tt group by MessageID having count(*) =3
```

Comment: this query returns messagesid  that have 21, 81,105 and more in flowstatusid  but i want messageid that have just only these 3 numbers: 21, 81,105 not more

Comment: @user3237339 did you try second query. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database type but I've found some other tickets which explain how to concatenate values from multiple records.

Postgress: [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column)

Oracle : [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

You can use this concatenated field in a condition with an equality match:

```
where myconcatresult = '21,81,105'
```

I don't know how this will perform :)