# Display result in one line

Tags: postgresql, psql

Couldn't find such question answered. I'm selecting one column from the table and I want to have output in one line in psql console to be easily copied.

```
select id from my_table;
```

Instead of

```
  id  
------
 1295
 1359
  568
   36
  395
  569
 1216
 1296
```

I would like to see

```
1295 1359 568 36 395 569 1216 1296
```

Is it possible in psql console?

Comment: Related: [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43870/190597)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT string_agg(id::text, ' ') FROM my_table;
```

The cast to `text` is probably necessary if `id` is not a string type.

See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

Comment: Thanks! That works fine together with \x auto enabled.