# SQL query to combine all the answer which has same question id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have to design the database table for my questioner form. I am using Postgres DB. The earlier approach I had taken given below as my number of the question was fixed and the requirement was the one question can only have one answer.

```
id  submit_by_id    q-1   q-2   q-3
```

```
1       12           a     b     c
2       12           a     b     c
3       11           a     b     c
```

but later the requirement has changed and one answer can have multiple answers. I don't want to save answer as the JSON format since I have to perform the search, filter, and sorting operation. The problem with the above design is that if you want to save multiple answers you have to repeat redundant information. for example

```
id  submit_by_id    q-1   q-2   q-3
```

```
1       12           a     b     c
2       12           a     b     c
3       11           a     b     c
4       12           d     b     c
```

to overcome this problem I have design two separate table

question table

```
id  question
```

```
1   xyz     
2   abc     
3   cda
```

answer table

```
id  submit_by_id    question_id    answer
```

```
1       12             1            espn
2       12             1            star
3       11             2            xyz
4       11             3            abc
```

That way the number of repetitive information could be less. 
So the question is how do get the collective answer from the query. I want to send the response like

```
[{q1:[a,c]}, {q2:[a]}]
```

Or is there any better way to do this.

Comment: From a database structure you are correct. Not sure what you mean by sending the response. Is there some piece of code that is converting result set to json, or is the database doing that itself. Maybe post the query or other code in the query.

Comment: I want to write the `sql` query which can merge the answers of same question into one

Comment: Your comment "merge the answers of same question into one" is not clear & your question "how to get the collective answer from the query" is not clear. Those are fuzzy. Use enough words, phrases, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly say what you mean. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510

Comment: @mehdi.loa That's exactly I was looking for. Many thanks