# Returning values with same id as one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Apologies if this has been answered but trying to word this question was a nightmare to wrap my head around.

Essentially I have a table

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 15618 | 6 |
| 15618 | 109 |
| 15618 | 659 |
| 27248 | 245 |
| 27248 | 6 |
| 27248 | 7 |
| 27248 | 6499 |

and I essentially want a query that returns

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 15618 | 6, 109, 659 |
| 27248 | 245, 6, 7, 6499 |

Comment: Have a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use arrays for this purpose:

```
select post_id, array_agg(tag_id order by tag_id)
from t
group by post_id;
```

You *can* use `string_agg(tag_id, ', ' order by tag_id)` if you really want a string.  In general, though, I find that arrays are much more versatile.

Comment: Arrays work fine. The format of the result isn't an issue. Just couldn't wrap my head around a way to make the result I wanted happen. I even looked at join and such