# How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'WITH RECURSIVE' query?

Tags: postgresql

As a follow up to this question [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

I am looking for a way to concatenate the strings of a field within a `WITH RECURSIVE` query (and **NOT** using `GORUP BY`). So for example, I have a table:

```
ID   COMPANY_ID   EMPLOYEE
1    1            Anna
2    1            Bill
3    2            Carol
4    2            Dave
5    3            Tom
```

and I wanted to group by company_id, ordered by the count of `EMPLOYEE`, to get something like:

```
COMPANY_ID   EMPLOYEE
3            Tom
1            Anna, Bill
2            Carol, Dave
```

Comment: Why would you *not* use the simpler `GROUP BY` for the task? Also, please lead with your version of Postgres and an exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) for any such question. Can there be duplicate names? NULL values? Details matter.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple with `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ' ORDER BY employee) AS employees
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY company_id
ORDER  BY count(*), company_id;
```

Sorting in a subquery is typically faster:

```sql
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ') AS employees
FROM  (SELECT company_id, employee FROM tbl ORDER BY 1, 2) t
GROUP  BY company_id
ORDER  BY count(*), company_id;
```

As academic proof of concept: an rCTE solution without using any aggregate or window functions:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
          company_id, employee, ARRAY[employee] AS employees
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.company_id, e.employee, r.employees || e.employee
   FROM   rcte r
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT t.employee
      FROM   tbl t
      WHERE  t.company_id = r.company_id
      AND    t.employee   > r.employee
      ORDER  BY t.employee
      LIMIT  1
      ) e
   )
SELECT company_id, array_to_string(employees, ', ') AS employees
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
          company_id, cardinality(employees) AS emp_ct, employees
   FROM   rcte
   ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY emp_ct, company_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8788ce017c7b8abd3a2773047acbf3a7)*

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

Answer (score 1):

No `group by` here:

```
select * from tarded;
┌────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ company_id │ employee │
├────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│  1 │          1 │ Anna     │
│  2 │          1 │ Bill     │
│  3 │          2 │ Carol    │
│  4 │          2 │ Dave     │
│  5 │          3 │ Tom      │
└────┴────────────┴──────────┘
(5 rows)

with recursive firsts as (
  select id, company_id, 
         first_value(id) over w as first_id, 
         row_number() over w as rn,
         count(1) over (partition by company_id) as ncompany,
         employee
    from tarded
  window w as (partition by company_id 
                   order by id)
), names  as (
  select company_id, id, employee, rn, ncompany
    from firsts 
   where id = first_id
  union all
  select p.company_id, c.id, concat(p.employee, ', ', c.employee), c.rn, p.ncompany
    from names p
         join firsts c
           on c.company_id = p.company_id
          and c.rn = p.rn + 1
)
select company_id, employee 
  from names
 where rn = ncompany
 order by ncompany, company_id;
┌────────────┬─────────────┐
│ company_id │  employee   │
├────────────┼─────────────┤
│          3 │ Tom         │
│          1 │ Anna, Bill  │
│          2 │ Carol, Dave │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: this query is better than Erwin's answers. because it allow employee to have duplicated value.