# Extract all substrings bounded by the same characters

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

Given a name_loc column of text like the following:

```
{"Charlie – White Plains, NY","Wrigley – Minneapolis, MN","Ana – Decatur, GA"}
```

I'm trying to extract the names, ideally separated by commas:

```
Charlie, Wrigley, Ana
```

I've gotten this far:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(name_loc AS VARCHAR) from '"([^ –]+)')
FROM table;
```

which returns

```
Charlie
```

How can I extend this query to extract all names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents, though I'm rather new to postgreSQL *and* I had to copy the 1st piece from @Marth's his answer:

```
WITH input(name_loc) AS (
    VALUES ('{"Charlie – White Plains, NY","Wrigley – Minneapolis, MN","Ana – Decatur, GA"}')
         , ('{"Other - somewhere"}') 
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name_loc, '{?(,)?"(\w+)[^"]+"}?','\1\2', 'g') FROM input;
```

| regexp_replace |
| --- |
| Charlie,Wrigley,Ana |
| Other |

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `regexp_matches` (to extract the names), `array_agg` (to regroup all matches in a row) and `array_to_string` (to format the array as you'd like, e.g. with a comma separator):

```
WITH input(name_loc) AS (
    VALUES ('{"Charlie – White Plains, NY","Wrigley – Minneapolis, MN","Ana – Decatur, GA"}')
         , ('{"Other - somewhere}') -- added this to show multiple rows do not get merged
)
SELECT array_to_string(names, ', ')
FROM input
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg(name)
    FROM regexp_matches(name_loc, '"(\w+)', 'g') AS f(name)
) AS f(names);
```

| array_to_string |
| --- |
| Charlie, Wrigley, Ana |
| Other |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YC9BXguPtVUMNTtzeGNyC/1)

Comment: Nice, you fiddle is empty though.

Comment: Oops, looks like the "copy as markdown" feature adds a link to no fiddle if you didn't save it first. Thanks, I updated it.

Comment: Works now! Great. I also added an answer where I copy pasted your first few lines. As I'm rather new to postgreSQL I hope you don't mind. ALso, your 2nd line is missing an double quote =)

Answer (score 0):

Your string literal happens to be a valid **[array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)**.
(Maybe not by coincidence? And the column should be type `text[]` to begin with?)

If that's the reliable format, there is a safe and simple solution:

```sql
SELECT t.id, x.names
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(split_part(elem, ' – ', 1), ', ') AS names
   FROM   unnest(t.name_loc::text[]) elem
   ) x;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT id, string_agg(split_part(elem, ' – ', 1), ', ') AS names
FROM   (SELECT id, unnest(name_loc::text[]) AS elem FROM tbl) t 
GROUP  BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=9b019061fd8c7a0fc17c60d82346e446)*

##### Steps

1. Unnest the array with `unnest()` in a `LATERAL CROSS JOIN`, or directly in the `SELECT` list.

   - [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
2. Take the first part with `split_part()`. I chose `' – '` as delimiter, not just `' '`, to allow for names with nested space like "Anne Nicole". See:

   - [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)
3. Aggregate results with `string_agg()`. I added no particular order as you didn't specify one.

   - [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)