# How to group SQL entries by truncated/modified fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want to group all entries in my table by their `user_type` property.
However the `user_type` entries exist in a `{type of user} {date account was created}` format, e.g.

```
id | user_type
--------------
01 | 'admin 2024-03-01'
02 | 'admin 2024-03-01'
03 | 'user 2024-03-02'
04 | 'user 2024-03-02'
05 | 'premium_user 2024-03-03'
```

I want to get the counts of each type of user, ignoring the date at the end of the value.  So for the above example, my query would return:

```
user_type      | count
----------------------
'admin'        | 2
'user'         | 2
'premium_user' | 1
```

The user types are subject to change, so I can't hardcode in filters such as `select count(id) where user_type like 'admin %'`.

Comment: Unrelated but since user type and creation date are very different attributes, why not have them in separate columns instead of a composite one? This would make things so much faster and easier.

Comment: Agree with -Stefanov.sm.  You _can_ query the data like you want (as shown in the answers below), but it's a hack. If this is important information, create a better table with the "correct" structure (i.e., having separate user_type and create_date columns). Maybe you're stuck that table as is, but could you create a view that cleans up the structure, so that your user_type hack is isolated in one place (in the definition of the view)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `SUBSTRING()` with a regular expression here:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(user_type from '^\w+') AS user_type, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_type
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Here is a working [SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0-i8SeSs).

Comment: Perfect thanks! But what does the regex `'^\w+'` mean? Will it still work if the base `user_type` has multiple spaces, e.g. `premium mobile user 2024-03-03`?

Comment: `^\w+` means match the first word in the column, so no, it wouldn't work if there were multiple spaces.  In that case, I might use a regex replacement approach which removes the trailing date. e.g. `REGEXP_REPLACE(user_type, '\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$', '')`, see the demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/YlEvHM2G

Comment: `SUBSTRING(user_type from '^([^0-9]+) ')`  would do the trick for embedded spaces. Yet Erwin Brandstetter's `left(user_type, -11)` would be much faster.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Using `^\D+` is probably a bad idea, because maybe a name could have a digit in it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fair enough, it could. It's hard to fight a flawed data design.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need to split that column into two columns: `user_type text` (or some enumeration type) and `date_created date`.

While stuck with your unfortunate design - and if the trailing date has the fixed format your sample data suggests - [**`left()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.8.1.1.1) with a negative length to truncate the last 11 characters is simplest & cheapest (much cheaper than a regular expression):

```sql
SELECT left(user_type, -11) AS user_type, count(*) AS count
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC;
```

The solution is for Postgres. You also tagged Redshift, which is not Postgres at all. There, [`left()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LEFT.html) does not support negative length. You might work around with:

```
substring(user_type, 1, length(user_type) - 11)
```

About the numeric reference in `GROUP BY 1` and `ORDER BY 2`:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

That works in Postgres *and* Redshift.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yl27-q8F)

Comment: What would happen if a given record _didn't_ end with a date?

Comment: Wouldn't work, obviously.